# ASP:NET ajax function does not work after onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to show the value of the selected index of a dropdownlist by using an ajax function. It does not work. I try to debug it by using the console and i saw that error `500 (Internal Server Error)` What is causing that problem ? The implementation is below

Ajax functions:

```
        function showDdlValue(ddl) {
        var value = ddl.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AdminPanel.aspx/getData",
            data: '{color: "' + value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

Html:

```
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel5" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>Show Shoes</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate runat="server">                                                               
                    <asp:Repeater ID="shoeRepeater" OnItemDataBound="shoeRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table border="1" style="border-color:#ff9900; width:400px; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="6" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
                                        <image src="shoeImages/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImagePath") %>"></image>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BrandName") %> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ModelName") %> 
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Price: $<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Price") %>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Size: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Size") %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Color:<asp:DropDownList ID="colorList1" onchange="showDdlValue(this)" runat="server">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Quantity: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity") %>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

Web method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private String getData(String color) 
    {
        return "Hello " + color;
    }
```

Comment: Look at the response back from the server...

Comment: Try removing `contentType` option and btw, looks like your server doesn't return JSON at all, so remove `dataType` too. But `500 (Internal Server Error)` means error is on server side. Just be aware, i know nothing about ASP.net, so...

Comment: @A.Wolff i removed both of these types but after the event alert box comes with undefined instead of value

Comment: @Tartar: `undefined` makes sense if you think about it. Why is it undefined? The server never sent back an answer. Why didn't it send an answer? Well, you said it yourself, there is an `Internal Server Error`. Where did that error occur? `Internal`. That means your backend threw an exception. Your javascript cannot fix that (unless, of course, it's due to a faulty ajax call). But to fix this, you need to look at the rest of the error message you get, and check the offending code in the *backend*, not the *frontend*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access specifier of the webmethod to `public`. It is not accessible when we set it as `private`

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDdlValue(ddl) {
    var value = ddl.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AdminPanel.aspx/getData",
        data: {'color':  value },
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

WEB METHOD

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public String getData(String color) 
{
    return "Hello " + color;
}
```

Try this